# Choosing SQL Server data types for maximum speed

Tags: sql-server, database-design, types, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm designing a database that will need to be optimized for maximum speed.

All the database data is generated once from something I call an input database (which holds the data I'm editing, mainly some polylines, markers, etc for google maps).

So the database is not subject to editing, but it needs to hold as many data as it can for quickly displaying results to the user (routes across town, custom polylines, etc).

The question is: choosing smaller data types for example like smallint over int will improve performance or it will affect it? Space is not quite a problem, after some quick calculations, the database will not exceed 200mb, and there will not be tables with more than 100.000 rows (average will be around 5.000).

I'm asking this because I read some articles around the internet and some say that smaller data types improve performance others say that it affects it because additional processing must be done. I'm aware that for smaller databases probably results are not noticeable, but I'm interested in every bit because I'm expecting many requests which will trigger a lot more queries.

The hosting environment is gonna be Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 R2.

**EDIT 1:** Just to give you an example because I don't have a proper table structure yet:
I'm going to have a table which will hold public transportation lines (somewhere around 200), identified by a unique number in real life, and which is going to be referenced in all sorts of tables and on which all sorts of operations are going to be made. These referencing tables will hold the largest amount of data.

Because lines have unique numbers, I have thought of 3 examples of designs:

1. The PK is the line number of datatype: smallint
2. The PK is the line number of datatype: int
3. The PK is something different (identity for example) and the line number is stored in a different field.
4. Just for the sake of argument, because I used this on the 'input database' which is not subject to optimization, the PK is a GUID (16 bytes); if you like, you can make a comparison of how bad is this compared to others, if it really is

So keep in mind that the PK is going to be referenced in at least 15 tables, some of which will have over 50.000 rows (the rest averaging 5.000 as I said above) which are going to be subject to constant querying and manipulation, and I'm interested in every bit of speed that I can get.

I can detail this even more if you need. Thanks

**EDIT 2:** And another question related to this came to my mind, think it fits into this discussion:

Will I see any performance improvements **in this specific scenario** if I use native SQL queries from inside my .NET application rather than using LINQ to SQL? I know LINQ is strongly optimized and generates very good queries performance-wise, but still, sure worth asking. Thanks again.

Comment: **YES!** choosing the right data type is crucial in your design. Smaller datatypes equal less bytes needing to be shuffled around - so that can definitely help! Also, things like using `VARCHAR(MAX)` for all string column out of lazyness are extremely disadvantageous - those "max" datatypes are handled differently from "regular" `Varchar(n)` columns... (negative impact on performance, too)

Comment: Regarding the PK - read [GUIDs as Primary and Clustering Key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) and [Disk space is cheap ... that's NOT the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx) by Kimberly Tripp. Using a GUID as clustering key is a **horribly bad** idea - it leads to really bad index fragmentation and thus slows down insert, updates, deletes and selects.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the article, I'm gonna put more time into reading about clustered indexes, because I'm not very aware of what they are and how they behave. Anyway, I intuited that GUID is a bad idea for a PK, but now I know why and how bad it is. But what about smallint vs int? I'm totally ignorant when it comes to low-level programming, but some say that although smallint needs less storage space, additional processing is made which consumes time.

Comment: You generally don't want to use an "external" identifier like route number as your PK because that could change. #3 is your best choice because you leave yourself options if a route number changes. It sounds like a smallint IDENTITY column would be the right PK for this particular case. Using a smallint versus int will help your indexing. You will have more records per physical page because you're using a smaller datatype.

Comment: @RobGarrison Generally you're right, but in my case, I'm not concerned about this issue and about none related to 'things that change' because the data practically doesn't change inside the database. Think about it as something similar to compiling. The input database (which does not need to be optimized) is the source code and the database I'm trying to optimize is the binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you point to some articles that say that smaller data types = more processing? Keeping in mind that even with SSDs most workloads today are I/O-bound (or memory-bound) and not CPU-bound.

Particularly in cases where the PK is going to be referenced in many tables, it will be beneficial to use the smallest data type possible. In this case if that's a `SMALLINT` then that's what I would use (though you say there are about 200 values, so theoretically you could use `TINYINT` which is half the size and supports 0-255). Where you need to exercise caution is if you aren't 100% sure that there will always be ~200 values. Once you need 256 you're going to have to change the data type in all of the affected tables, and this is going to be a pain. So sometimes a trade-off is made between accommodating future growth and squeezing the absolute most performance today. If you don't know for certain that you will never exceed 255 or 32,000 values then I would probably just an `INT`. Unless you also don't know that you won't ever exceed 2 billion values, in which case you would use `BIGINT`.

The difference between `INT`/`SMALLINT`/`TINYINT` is going to be more noticeable in disk space than in performance. (And if you're on Enterprise, the differences in both disk space and performance can be offset quite a bit using data compression - particularly while your `INT` values all fit within `SMALLINT`/`TINYINT`, though in the latter case it really will be negligible because the values are unique.) On the other hand, the difference between any of these and `GUID` is going to be much more noticeable in both performance and disk space. Marc gave some great links from Kimberly; [I wrote this article](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-should-i-choose-for-my-primary-key.html) in 2003 and while it's a little dated it does contain most of the salient points that are still relevant today.

Another trade-off that sometimes needs to be considered (though not in your specific case, it seems) is whether values need to be unique across multiple systems. This is where you might need to sacrifice some performance in order to meet business requirements. In a lot of cases folks take the easy way and resign themselves to `GUID`. But there are other solutions too, such as identity ranges, a central custom sequence generator, and the new `SEQUENCE` object in SQL Server 2012. [I wrote about `SEQUENCE`](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/11/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-sequence) back in 2010 when the first public beta of SQL Server 2012 was released.

Comment: The thing with tinyint is that line numbers are not consecutive, and the range is 1 - 800. I am sure that they're not going to exceed 255 values, so I could use tinyint but that would mean to store the number in a separate column. Sure some additional 200 smallints are worth for 200.000 tinyints instead of smallints in referencing tables, but what I can think of right now is the pain when I'm going to debug, and sure it's gonna be a lot of it.

Comment: Then I would say stick with `SMALLINT`. As I alluded to above, you're not really gaining much at all between `SMALLINT` and `TINYINT`, and I would prefer to stick with the natural key when it exists than to create some arbitrary surrogate. Even though the "natural" key is in itself just a surrogate from another system.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the advice. I think I read articles that said smaller data types = more processing a long time ago and this idea stuck in my head. I found some of them but they are also old, and they also mentioned that it's not the case with present-day systems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to provide some more details about the tables structure and sample queries that will be running against them. Based on the information that you have provided I believe that impact of choosing smaller data types will be just a couple of percents and I would suggest to give higher attention to indexes that you will have. SQL Server does a good job on suggesting what indexes to create by providing you with execution plans for your queries and tuning advisor tool

Comment: I updated the question with an example that I think should make it a little more clear.

Answer (score -2):

One suggestion that I have is to incorporate a decimal datatype instead of using a combination of fields.  For example, instead of having a table with Date (YYYYMMDD), Store (SSSS), and Item (IIII), I would recommend...YYYYMMDD.SSSSIIII.  Especially when querying multiple tables with this same key combination, it dramatically improves processing time.